# How to use openssl shake256 hash string into a specified length hash-string?

Tags: linux, openssl, hashsum

How to use `openssl` `shake256` hash string to a specified length hash-string?
I use the following command to generate a `shake256` hash string with the default length in Linux:

```
echo -n 28713 | openssl shake256
```

It works, but I want shorter return value.

In the paper:
[SHA-3 Wiki](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA%E5%AE%B6%E6%97%8F)
Shake256 can hash string with a specified length.

Comment: In what paper? You need to be more specific if you want anyone else to know what you refer to.

Comment: Many papers, like this:https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA%E5%AE%B6%E6%97%8F
Shake256 is SHA-3 family, and its output hash value(bits) is d (arbitrary).

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in `openssl-3.0.0-alpha10` and later with the `-xoflen` flag. Earlier versions do not support it.

Source:

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/c39f43534d4f359bdfee617f70f89b114c9f2cca